# Form validation with JQuery not work

Tags: jquery, html

I'm learning JQuery, I want to validate a form basic form without using bootstrap validation, in my basic code, JQuery not detect anything when if I click on the button.

JQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("agregar_proveedor").click(function(e) {

    var name = $('nombre_proveedor').val();

    if(name=="") {
        $("nombre_empresa").attr("placeholder", "Ingrese nombre").placeholder();
        $("form_group_nombre").addClass('has error');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;   
    }

});

});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="panel contenedor panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Agregar Proveedor</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form action="?proveedores" method="POST" name="form_proveedores" class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Datos</legend>
        <div class="form-group" name="form_group_nombre">
          <label for="inputNombre" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nombre empresa</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputNombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre empresa" type="text" name="nombre_empresa">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputDireccion" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Direccion</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputDireccion" placeholder="Ingrese direccion" type="text" name="direccion">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputTelefono" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Telefono</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputTelefono" placeholder="Ingrese telefono" type="text" name="telefono">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block" name="agregar_proveedor">Agregar</button>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>        
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: add id Then getting value like this $('#nombre_proveedor').val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at your selector.

1. By id the selector should be `$("#Element_ID")`
2. By class the selector should be `$(".Element_ID")`
3. By name the selector should be `$("Tag[name='Element_Name']")`
4. By tag the selector should be `$("Tag")`
5. By attribute the selector should be `$("Tag[Attribute_Name='Attribute_Value']")`

Please check below working snippet. I have corrected selectors in it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button[name='agregar_proveedor']").click(function(e) {

    var name = $('#inputNombre').val();

    if(name=="") {
      $("#inputNombre").attr("placeholder", "Ingrese nombre");
      $("form[name='form_proveedores']").addClass('has error');
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;   
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel contenedor panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Agregar Proveedor</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form action="?proveedores" method="POST" name="form_proveedores" class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Datos</legend>
        <div class="form-group" name="form_group_nombre">
          <label for="inputNombre" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nombre empresa</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputNombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre empresa" type="text" name="nombre_empresa">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputDireccion" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Direccion</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputDireccion" placeholder="Ingrese direccion" type="text" name="direccion">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputTelefono" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Telefono</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputTelefono" placeholder="Ingrese telefono" type="text" name="telefono">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block" name="agregar_proveedor">Agregar</button>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , a last question , why $("form_group_nombre").addClass('has error'); in my code not work ?

Comment: Please check the updated snippet I have shown how to use selector of the form by its name... as such it is the selector for the form and you want the selector by name of the form so I have shared in my answer how to create selector by name of the element..

Comment: It should be $("form[name='form_group_nombre']").addClass('has error');

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors is incorrect. Use **.** for class selector, **#** for id selector. So, click listener like the following.

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
 var name = $('#inputNombre').val();
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, you are not attaching events or identifying your elements in a proper way. I see that you have given `agregar_proveedor` which is the  `name` for your button. There are many ways of identifying elements. i.e. identifying with `id` which is using `"#"` - `$("#elementID")`, identifying using `class` which is using `"."` - `$(".elementClassName")` and with name or similar attributes. Basically its good to use with `id` or `class`. Since you have are trying with `name`, you should attach it as `$('button[name="agregar_proveedor"]')`. Below is update for your code.

```
$('button[name="agregar_proveedor"]').click(function(e) {

     var name = $('nombre_proveedor').val();
     if(name=="") {
         $('input[name="nombre_empresa"]').attr("placeholder", "Ingrese nombre");
         //You can replace with $("#inputNombre") i.e. getting element with its "id"
         $('form[name="form_group_nombre"]').addClass('has error');
         e.preventDefault();
         return false;   
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

tyr to this...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#agregar_proveedor").click(function(e) {

    var name = $('#inputNombre').val();
    
    if(name=="") {
        $(".form-control").addClass('has error');
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;   
    }

});

});
```

```css
.error{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div class="panel contenedor panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Agregar Proveedor</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form action="?proveedores" method="POST" name="form_proveedores" class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Datos</legend>
        <div class="form-group" name="form_group_nombre">
          <label for="inputNombre" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nombre empresa</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputNombre" placeholder="Ingrese nombre empresa" type="text" name="nombre_empresa">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputDireccion" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Direccion</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputDireccion" placeholder="Ingrese direccion" type="text" name="direccion">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputTelefono" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Telefono</label>
          <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input class="form-control" id="inputTelefono" placeholder="Ingrese telefono" type="text" name="telefono">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block" id="agregar_proveedor" name="agregar_proveedor">Agregar</button>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>        
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button[name='agregar_proveedor']").click(function(e) {
        $('.form-horizontal input').map(function(){
            if( !$(this).val() ) {
                $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
            }
            else if ($(this).val()) {
                $(this).css('background-color:none');;
            }   
        });
    });
});
```